# Count child number using Xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Return the number of child in a node.

This is my XML:

```
<LIGHT_INFORMATION_LIST>
    <LIGHT_INFORMATION>
        <LIGHT_COLOUR>W-G</LIGHT_COLOUR>
    </LIGHT_INFORMATION>
    <LIGHT_INFORMATION>
        <LIGHT_COLOUR>W-R</LIGHT_COLOUR>
    </LIGHT_INFORMATION>
    <LIGHT_INFORMATION>
        <LIGHT_COLOUR>R</LIGHT_COLOUR>
    </LIGHT_INFORMATION>
    <LIGHT_INFORMATION>
        <LIGHT_COLOUR>G</LIGHT_COLOUR>
    </LIGHT_INFORMATION>
    <LIGHT_INFORMATION>
        <LIGHT_COLOUR>W</LIGHT_COLOUR>
    </LIGHT_INFORMATION>
</LIGHT_INFORMATION_LIST>
```

Request Output:
The output request is 5. (The number of child called LIGHT_INFORMATION)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(LIGHT_INFORMATION_LIST/LIGHT_INFORMATION)"/>
```

Return 5

Comment: Your solution needs a **context**, i.e. `<xsl:template match="/">`. It will not work in another context.